# BASH instead of CSH while running Commands on a Remote Linux Server over SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, csh

I would like to run a command on a remote server using ssh, under bash, while my default session is csh.

minimal example (true command is more complex and is generated by my IDE remote debugger):

```
ssh hostname 'ls | head'
```

I don't have admin privileges. Trying `chsh -s /bin/bash` results with an error `chsh: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.`

I tried adding to .cshrc the following

```
setenv SHELL /bin/bash
exec /bin/bash --login
```

but it freezes the console when sending the command through ssh (while regular ssh works)

Any idea how to solve that?

NOTE: I must have a solution that would configure the host, because I don't have access to the ssh command which is generated automatically by the debugger of my IDE. On the IDE I can only set the host name and port number. (EDIT) Therefore solutions like `ssh hostname '/bin/bash -c "ls | head"'` wont apply

EDIT2:
Actual command shown by IDE (again, I can't edit it):

```
ssh://username@localhost:2213/home/lab/username/anaconda2/envs/tf_011b/bin/python -u /specific/a/home/cc/cs/username/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 41823 --file /home/lab/username/remote_py/nlteach/show_attend_and_tell/train_saat_classifier.py --train_dir=/home/lab/username/nlteach/output/train/d=cub/imSD=11%imSP=rnd%tcSP=cvpr16/CSat/res50%lr0_02LrDTexpLrDc0_938OrmspWDc0/emb=512%ldTrn=0%nU=512%noHid=1%lr=0_02%lrDT=fix%lrDc=1%o=rmsp/
```

I am not sure why, but on a bash enabled server it works, while it fails on the csh host.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the actual command(s) being sent (obviously scrub any sensitive information).

Comment: @bishop, edited accordingly

Comment: If you don't have permission to use `chsh`, there's no way to change the default shell that's used. If you can't put `bash -c "whatever"` into the command, I think you're screwed.

Comment: Can you send a command to run a script? You could put the commands you want into a bash script, and then run the script.

Comment: @Barmar I was going to suggest the OP could csh alias the first command sent to a bash script that passes the arguments through. However, having seen the command, I'm not quite sure what's failing in csh as it appears to be just one command. It might be lack of proper quoting on the special characters way out to the right.

Comment: Your example command and the command sent by the IDE is valid `csh` as well as `bash`.

Comment: (1) the error I get is ":/ Event not found" (2) Is it possible to elaborate on .cshrc s.t. it will feed/pipe the command to `exec /bin/bash`?

Comment: That error message suggests that something is sending a command with history substitution in it, which involves the `!` character. I don't see that anywhere in the question.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. The IDE doesn't show anywhere that it sends the `!` character.

Comment: Maybe it's in your `.cshrc`

Comment: You can set the history substitution character to something besides `!` using the `histchars` variable. Also lines beginning with `^` undergo history substitution (hmm can't be that the error message would be different). If you see either of those things in your `.cshrc` that's a problem.

Comment: @user2476373 What happens if you use `setenv SHELL /bin/bash; /bin/bash --login; exit 0` without the `exec` as your `.cshrc`?

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, if you're actually using `tcsh` instead of plain `csh`, the `.tcshrc` file takes priority.

Comment: I have to switch to a different task. I'll update tomorrow with the results. Thanks so far!

Comment: I have been trying to find an answer to your problem by using reverse-ssh, and commands option in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. So far unsuccessful. Maybe you'll get some hint from this.

Comment: When you run a command through ssh, sshd executes your shell with additional arguments, like `-c "command to run"`. `exec /bin/bash` doesn't pass any additional arguments to bash, which creates an interactive bash session, which is not what you want. Try using the `$command` csh variable if set. Also file a ticket to your IT and request shell change.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke `bash` on the remote side, telling it what commands to run:

```
ssh hostname '/bin/bash -c "ls | head"'
```

If the command is too complicated (eg because of quotation mark escaping), then write your commands to a script, copy the script, then run the script:

```
scp script.bash hostname:/tmp/
ssh hostname '/bin/bash /tmp/script.bash'
```

Comment: Thanks. See my bottom note. I don't have access for manipulating the command sent from the client